SSIS Package runs on one server, throws error on another
I have an ssis package that runs on a SQL Server 2016 instance without issue.
When run it on a SQL Server 2022 instance, it fails with the error:

Cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode

The package is reading data from a flatfile and loading it into a table.
The database is identical on both servers, database is backed up and restored immediately to the SQL Server 2022 instance.
Collation is the same at instance, database and table levels.
The only difference I can see is the version of SQL Server.
Can anyone advise what might be happening here?

We need more information here, such as what the task that is specifically failing is doing. If in a data flow task, what source/destination/transformation type and what it's doing.

I know I have received this error when the data type is different from the source to the destination (usually its VARCHAR vs NVARCAR data type issue).  Though if you have it and the DBs are exactly the same.  You may just need to go into the package, open up the data flow so it can update the data types and close it (that has worked for me in the past as well).

When you deployed the package to 2022, did you update the project's target version prior to deployment? I'm seen some "interesting" behaviours occur when a package targets the wrong version.

@brad -juat opening the package in visual studio and running it before deployment resolved the issue. Unsure why, as nothing change, the file was the same, the database was the same, collation and data types were the same. All that changed was a migration to a new SQL instance.

That sometimes happens when DB versions change, it needs to update the meatdata.

Thanks for the replies.
Advice from @brad resolved the issue
Opening the package in visual studio and running it before deployment was the resolution. Unsure why, as nothing change, the file was the same, the database was the same, collation and data types were the same & target version was the same. All that changed was a migration to a new SQL instance.
